# Broken Tail Recursion?

Tags: programming-languages, scheme, tail-recursion

I have studied programming language course, I have this variant of Scheme code in the slide:

```
; (listof any) -> (listof any[no-cons])

(define (remove-pairs l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) '()]
    [else
      (let ([ans
              (if (cons? (first l))
                  (begin (free! (first l))
                         (remove-pairs (rest l)))
                  (cons (first l)
                        (remove-pairs (rest l))))])
       (free! l) ; <- this will break our tail recursion.
       ans)]))
```

In the code, `(free! l)` will break our tail recursion. I don't know what does this function do that and I cannot get any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to tell what this function is supposed to do without seeing the code for `free!`. What can be inferred, is that the procedure *deletes* each element in the list that is not a `cons` cell, building and returning a new list with only the elements that were not `cons` cells from the start.

It's incorrect to state that the function is tail recursive - it never was to begin with, no matter what `free!` does, the recursive calls are not in tail position.

Here's the *correct* way to implement the inferred functionality using tail recursion, notice that the way the recursion was structured in the question was completely wrong and not tail recursive at all:

```
(define (remove-pairs l)
  (let loop ((lst (reverse l))
             (acc '()))
    (cond [(empty? lst)
           acc]
          [(cons? (first lst))
           (free! (first lst)) ; whatever that is
           (loop (rest lst) acc)]
          [else
           (loop (rest lst) (cons (first lst) acc))])))
```

From a more practical point of view, you can get the same functionality using `filter`, although this is not guaranteed to be tail recursive:

```
(define (remove-pairs l)
  (filter (lambda (x)
            (cond [(cons? x)
                   (free! x) ; whatever that is
                   #f]
                  [else #t]))
          l))
```

Either way, this is how it works:

```
(remove-pairs '(1 (2 4) 3 5 (6 8) 7 (9 11)))
=> '(1 3 5 7)
```